# Does Liferay uses active internet connection to deploy to localhost?

Tags: localhost, liferay

I am using liferay for the first time. And I saw one thing today. If I am not connected to the internet it won't allow you to deploy the project even on localhost.

Is this in built in functionality of liferay or there can be some problem at my end? i mean in my machine.

Comment: Please define what you mean with "deploy", as there is more than one way to deploy to a Liferay server. For example I'm deploying directly into my application server, which is working without any internet connection.

Comment: Seconding @TobiasLiefke: I understand neither the question nor the accepted answer. And trust me, I've installed quite a few Liferay systems - on- and offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think YES,

If you haven't stored the certificate locally in your system, it looks for it online. So if you have certificate stored already than the problem is at your end.

Comment: @Harshal What kind of certificate are you talking about? The original question had nothing to do with a certificate.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke, The licence certificate I am talking about. While registering Liferay it asks for a link of certificate or a folder directory of it. So if its via a link liferay checks into that link every time. As of my knowledge this is the only occurrence where liferay needs active connection.

Comment: Are you talking about _Liferay EE (Enterprise Edition)_? The CE (Community Edition) does _not_ have any certificate. And guessing from the comment of the OP, that he is using Liferay the first time, I would assume that he is using the CE.